# Is it haram to talk to a guy online as friends?

Tags: halal-haram, quran

i have a friend who is a male online and we text and sometimes play games together. i have no intention of being anything more than friends and i know i have a strong mind which can refrain from it. we have never seen eachothers face and sometimes we call while playing games but thats it and we only call so we can play the game and have more fun and talk about the game instead of texting. can someone who is well educated tell me if being friends with the opposite gender is haram? and if it has been said in the Qur'an? i have tried searching for answers but everyone gives me a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

Aslamu Walaykum

According to these verses of the holy Quran, it is strictly forbidden to have a friend that is the opposite gender:

33:32 O wives of the Prophet! You are not like any other women: if you are mindful ˹of Allah˺, then do not be overly effeminate in speech ˹with men˺ or those with sickness in their hearts may be tempted, but speak in a moderate tone.

24:30 ˹O Prophet!˺ Tell the believing men to lower their gaze and guard their chastity. That is purer for them. Surely Allah is All-Aware of what they do.

24:31 And tell the believing women to lower their gaze and guard their chastity, and not to reveal their adornments except what normally appears. Let them draw their veils over their chests, and not reveal their ˹hidden˺ adornments except to their husbands, their fathers, their fathers-in-law, their sons, their stepsons, their brothers, their brothers’ sons or sisters’ sons, their fellow women, those ˹bondwomen˺ in their possession, male attendants with no desire, or children who are still unaware of women’s nakedness. Let them not stomp their feet, drawing attention to their hidden adornments. Turn to Allah in repentance all together, believers, so that you may be successful.

Talking to someone of the opposite gender in person or via the internet is prohibited. Males should always look down and avoid talking to people who are of the opposite gender unless necessary.